# How many souls can I store in the Black Star to do enchanting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got a Black Star and I've read that it's supposed to be like an infinite black gem.

I would like to use it for enchanting.

How many souls can I carry in it?
Just one at the time?

I guess when I'll be using it to perform enchants, it won't disappear but just become empty, right?

Answer (score 10):

The black star is an infinite soul gem with the power to capture any soul, either from an NPC or a creature.

It functions exactly like a normal soul gem, only one soul at a time. When you use it to charge or enchant an item, it will not disappear, it will just become empty.

Comment: And I guess when I capture the soul of humanoids it'll be like a grand soul gem with grand soul in it?

Comment: yes its function exactly like a soul gem so yes it would be filled with a grand soul and act in a similar way to a grand soul gem.

Comment: You can only store humanoid souls in a black soul gem and according to the wiki, it acts like a black soul gem only if you get it purified by Nelacar(one of the quest markers for this quest in winterhold inn). Getting it purified by Azura will only make it a normal grand soul gem and you can't store humanoid souls in it.

Comment: And not all humanoid souls are created equal. Some will be below the 'grand' soul level.

Comment: @Praneeth i have proved this wrong numerous times do you actually own a black star? i do and i can capture any soul.

Comment: @Phantasm You are correct that [the Black Star can capture non-humanoid souls](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star_(item)#The_Black_Star). However, this is most likely a bug as the Black Star's definition describes it as "An unbreakable, reusable soul gem that can hold only black souls, these are obtained from killing humanoids".

Answer (score 5):

Lets answer your question(s) one at a time.

> How many souls can I carry in it?

Just one.

> Just one at the time?

Unfortunately yes.

> I guess when I'll be using it to perform enchants, it won't disappear
>   but just become empty, right?

Precisely.

The Black Star has two states: Empty and Filled with [inset soul level here]. Since I tend to have a bunch of petty through greater soul gems on me at all times I don't have to worry about storing deer or elk souls in my Black Star (what a waste that would be). In Skyrim souls will be stored in the lowest leveled compatable empty soul gem in your inventory [confirmed here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Trap).

> If an empty Soul Gem is available in your inventory, then the soul will fit into the smallest Gem available...

For more information about soul gems, the black star, enchanting and soul trapping see [this link](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Trap). At the bottom of the linked page, under "See also", you will find the additional links.

Comment: According to the comment above if I get it unlocked from Nelectar (as I in matter of fact did), then it should be the equivalent of having a grand gem/grand soul every time I store a humanoid soul right?

Comment: @Emanuele yes it is a grand soul every time you catch a soul but don't trust these comments you can indeed catch any soul in the black star.

Comment: @Emanuele It is the equivalent of having a black soul gem in your inventory. If it is empty (you can check if it empty or currently storing a soul by looking at it in your inventory) and you soul trap (and kill) a humanoid creature you will store their soul in the Black Star. If it is not empty you will attempt to store it in an empty black soul gem or tell you "There is no soul gem in your inventory capable of holding such a soul."

Comment: Ok, so if I can store something in the Black Star it does mean it is Grand soul or equivalent, right?

Comment: Not really a waste to catch an elk in Azura's Star/Black Star. Just dump the elk soul into a weapon to recharge it and you're ready to capture a fresh new grand/black soul.

Comment: @Emanuele a soul stored in the Black Star doesn't make it a Grand Soul. ANY soul (the important thing here is the ANY includes humanoid) can be stored in the Black Star. If you have only the empty Black Star in you inventory and you soul trap and kill a creature its soul will be stored in the Black Star. You can check the type of soul stored in the Black Star by looking at it in your inventory. Under the picutre of the item in your inventory or while enchanting, you will find text that indicates the type of soul stored in the Black Star.

Comment: Any black soul is automatically a grand soul. The black star can hold **any** soul, so if you kill a deer and it's your only gem, it will hold a petty soul.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, any humanoid soul IS a black soul, right?

Comment: @Emanuele yes humanoid souls are black souls.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to confirm that every time I kill a humanoid, no matter what level they are, I'll get a black soul! Cheers! :-)